# Kube Controller Manager CrashLoopBackOff

Tags: kubernetes

My `kube-controller-manager`keeps staying on `CrashLoopBackOff` status.

I found this upon looking in the logs of the pod:
`failed to create listener: failed to listen on 0.0.0.0:10252: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:10252: bind: address already in use`

Then I stumbled upon this article who fortunately was able to find a fix for it. Where he killed the process using the port and restarted his `kube-controller-manager` pod. https://medium.com/@deepeshtripathi/kubernetes-controller-pod-crashloopbackoff-resolved-16aaa1c27cfc

So I did follow the steps he made. When I have tried to get into the master node to find which process is using this port, I can't see anything that uses it.

```
root@ip:/# netstat -tunlp | grep 1025 
tcp6       0      0 :::10250                :::*                    LISTEN      1598/kubelet    
tcp6       0      0 :::10251                :::*                    LISTEN      7472/kube-scheduler
tcp6       0      0 :::10255                :::*                    LISTEN      1598/kubelet    
tcp6       0      0 :::10256                :::*                    LISTEN      5629/kube-proxy
```

Is there anyone else know any solution on how to fix this?

Comment: can you run `fuser -k 10252/tcp`.. and chek?

Comment: this magically fixed it!

Comment: I added this as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> failed to create listener: failed to listen on 0.0.0.0:10252: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:10252: bind: address already in use

According to the error message port `10252` is in use. So need to stop listening on this port. You can do that by running

`fuser -k 10252/tcp`